# Processing my image for submission (CANVAS) not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

One quick question. I want to process my canvas into the JotForm Api.
I tried doing it by chart only and it is working. But when doing it on the canvas itself it do not show any data in my JotForm.
This is my code

```
 //Listen for Jotform to get ready
JFCustomWidget.subscribe('ready', function (data) {
    //listen for button click
    var snapBtn = document.getElementById('snap')
    snapBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        screenshot();
    })

    // prep data
    function prepData(dataURL) {
        return {
            valid: true,
            value: JFCustomWidgetUtils.buildMetadata('imagelinks', [{
                'name': "Data from table",
                'base64': dataURL
            }])
        }
    }

    //process image for form submission   
    var resultChart, imageData;
    var submissionData = {
        valid: false,
        value: ''
    };
    // function screenshot() {

    //     document.querySelectorAll('.chartjs-render-monitor').forEach( chart => { chart.style.display !== 'none' ? resultChart = chart : ''} );
    //     if(resultChart){
    //         imageData = resultChart.toDataURL();
    //         submissionData = prepData( imageData );
    //         JFCustomWidget.sendData( submissionData );
    //     }
    // }
    function screenshot() {
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            scrollY: -window.scrollY,
            crossOrigin: 'Anonymous',
            allowTaint: true,
            foreignObjectRendering: true,
        }).then(function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            $data0101 = document.body.appendChild(canvas).toDataURL();
            document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        })
        document.querySelectorAll($data0101).forEach
        // document.querySelectorAll('.chartjs-render-monitor').forEach( chart => { chart.style.display !== 'none' ? resultChart = chart : ''} );
        if (resultChart) {
            imageData = $data0101;
            submissionData = prepData(imageData);
            JFCustomWidget.sendData(submissionData);
        }
    }
    //listen for submit event
    JFCustomWidget.subscribe('submit', function () {
        JFCustomWidget.sendSubmit(submissionData);
    });
});
```

The working code here is on the part where I commented it.

```
// function screenshot() {

//     document.querySelectorAll('.chartjs-render-monitor').forEach( chart => { chart.style.display !== 'none' ? resultChart = chart : ''} );
//     if(resultChart){
//         imageData = resultChart.toDataURL();
//         submissionData = prepData( imageData );
//         JFCustomWidget.sendData( submissionData );
//     }
// }
```

and here,

```
// document.querySelectorAll('.chartjs-render-monitor').forEach( chart => { chart.style.display !== 'none' ? resultChart = chart : ''} );
```

I need to get the canvas or the whole HTML itself that is on the actual monitor instead of just the chart I made.
Is there a way I can get my canvas to be inserted inside not the chart. I am lost at this area. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to this?